# Can I use Microsoft Graph API concept to integrate my Application with MS Teams. If yes, please elaborate

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, c#-3.0

I have .net application with me. Inside the application I want to add a functionality like the users can communicate between themselves by connecting to MS Teams. So I need my user to connect to MS Teams via my application. Please provide a step by step execution on this.

I don't have any idea on how to integrate my application with MS Teams. Somewhere I heard that it can be done using MS Graph API.

Comment: Please refer: 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/samples/integrating-web-apps  2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/samples/integrate-web-apps-overview#integrate-teams-in-your-external-app

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT That I gone through.. Any other information in your words ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) first to check if the feature was what you want.

Per my understanding, what you want maybe a web application and you can send messages in the webpage and finally it will be send to Teams. If I was right, then the API may help you. Microsoft graph api has the ability to `Send a new chatMessage in the specified channel or a chat.`

If you want to use this api, you need to have an Azure AD application then add api permission for this app. Then register this app to your web application, so that you can sign in your app to authenticate and authorize the graph api. Then  you need to compose your app to prepare the message content to be sent by the api.

Here's an [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph) to create web application and register aad app into the web app and call graph api.

Comment: If the API is not what you want, pls kindly let me know and I will delete my post. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is the one what I'm looking for. Really TQSM. Tiny Wang

Comment: if you think my post is helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answere by click the ✔ beside it to end this question? thanks in advance and this will also help others who met similar issue in the future more easier to find it. @UmeshChandra

Comment: Sure I'll do that. Thanks once again

Comment: thank you very much for your response as well : )